# Laravel 5: Moving current site to multi regional website ( /in, /eu, etc)

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, routes, laravel-5

My current site url is www.mysite.com and I wish to create a multi-regional website like www.mysite.com/in, www.mysite.com/eu, etc for multiple countries.

I am using larval 5.1 and I know the route::group method to do so.

But my code uses referential url all over the site(e.g. /home, /about-us) and I wish to change it to /in/home, /in/about-us, etc without hard coding the site url in every view or js file with the url country segment.

Is there a way to force all the links to traverse through the country segment?

Comment: I deleted my answer about the `base` tag because I realized it worked only with relative URLs, not absolute ones, so it doesn't seem like a solution to this problem after all. You could use subdomains (like eu.mysite.com) and the absolute links would work, but that does use a different url scheme than you presented, and would require different DNS and server setup.

Answer (score 0):

A good way could be combining a route that gets the intended language to localize to and a Middleware to set the localization if it supported--something like LocalizationMiddleware.

You can skip the middleware if you explicitly define it inside the route though.

```
Route::get("{locale}/home", function($locale) {
          App::setLocale($locale);
          // Define your route here
});
```

Middlewares are the new "filters" of Laravel 5, and you have to define it sepparately. You would create a new one with:

```
php artisan make:middleware LocalizationMiddleware
```

Then, you can find it in app/Http/Middleware/LocalizationMiddleware.php, and you could set the locale inside the handle() method.

Then, in your route, you would remove the locale code and specify that it needs to use your middleware.

```
Route::get("{locale}/home",
          ["middleware" => "LocalizationMiddleware", function($locale) {
          // Define your route here
}]);
```